# How to use PHP to generate HTML form to let user do complex searches on a database?

Tags: php, webforms

Let's imagine I have a database and I want to programatically allow the user to build queries. I am coding in PHP and will output an HTML form to let the user specify his query.

I know the names of all fields, their types (int/string/date, etc) and maybe also min/max.  How can I best present this visually to the user and let him select his queries?

At the moment, my logic is only `AND`, because I create a table with an entry for each DB field.

If the original input was free-form text (edit or memo), then I can put `<field name><operation><text input field>` where `operation` is a drop down list of 
`contains/doesn't contain/begins./ends/etc`. So he can specify `name begins "Mc"`, etc

If the original input was from a drop down list, the operation is just `equal/no equal` and he gets to choose again from that drop down list.

For integrs operation is `= != > >= =< <`

And so on, *BUT* while I can generate a table row for each and put a checkbox by it, I can't let user specify complex seraches like `(name beings"Mc" and salary>50000) || (name !=smith && title!="CEO))`

I hope that I explained that understandably. What I guess I am preferably looking for is a FOSS PHP compoinent to help me. Failing that, some advice ....  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to present my tables

http://datatables.net/

You can build the queries however you would like with JS, and **MAKE SURE YOU VALIDATE THE DATA SERVER-SIDE**

Note: There's a bit of a learning curve here if you're new to jQuery and Json, but IMO it's worth it.

Comment: +1 Thanks!  I will definitely look into it, although I have a prefernce for pure client side ...